# Word or a phrase that means your results could be biased toward what you predicted them to be

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, psychology

In psychology I recall we used a phrase or a word that meant that because you predicted the outcome of an experiment, then your results could be biased towards your prediction.

Either subconsciously or by having your predictions at the forethought of your memory then these predictions would have some sort of influencing factor on the results of the experiment.

Is there a word or a phrase to easily express this?

Comment: There are a couple of words that fit: _tendentious_, _biased_, _predisposed_.

Comment: I think maybe this question should be closed as just asking for a definition.

Comment: Perhaps related to "Clever Hans" ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans

Comment: Also, the subject matter is probably more applicable to the [CogSci branch of SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @3nafish  We do close for asking for definitions - General Reference - but in this case PP's supplied the definition and he's asking for the word.

Comment: We're not experts on scientific method. Ask at cogsci.SE. Also, investigator bias.

Comment: I wasn't looking for scientific method, hence my asking here and not cogsci. Words like tendentious, biased, predisposed, were good answers to my question. Thanks to @BillFranke

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is also the term [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) (Wikipedia), which exactly describes this idea.

Comment: Confirmation bias is similar, but the OP specifically asked for something that described when you "predicted the outcome of an experiment," whereas confirmation bias just refers to a general tendency of people to see things that confirm their beliefs, not specifically in an experiment.

Comment: "Confirmation bias (also called confirmatory bias or myside bias) is a tendency of people to favor information that confirms their beliefs **or hypotheses**." Hypotheses, you will recall, are those things that get tested in scientific experiments.

Comment: True.  I'm not saying you're wrong (which is why I gave you +1).  I'm just saying that confirmation bias is a hypernym of observer-expectancy because it can include confirmation of beliefs outside of experiments.

Comment: OK, point taken.

Comment: In practice, confirmation bias tends to imply bias towards "beliefs" or hypotheses in an informal sense, I think. So from that point of view it is perfectly fitting for the OP's description of "predictions at the forethought of your memory", but maybe not so much for *formal* predictions?

Answer (score 10):

It's a particular kind of [self-fulfilling prophecy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy) known as [observer-expectancy effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer-expectancy_effect).