# Looking for the phrase or idiom that means if you think or act in a certain way it often happens to come out that way

Tags: phrases, expressions, idiom-meaning

It's a well-known phrase or idiom (in the 20<sup>th</sup> Century...not sure about now, but it is still used sometimes) that means one's fearful (or can be pleasant too, sometimes) thoughts or actions actually end up bringing that fear (or pleasantness) or a bad outcome to reality...not exactly like karma or fate, but similar to/kind of like one's subconscious thoughts bring about actions & behavior that make it come true.

Seems like it's a 2-word phrase (maybe 3).

Comment: Sort of self fulfilling prophecy ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when people wrongly anticipate something and their actions eventually make it happen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102039/what-is-it-called-when-people-wrongly-anticipate-something-and-their-actions-eve) (+ at least one other duplicate)